# Ingest large amounts of csv data into elastic search on a daily basis

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

I have some fairly large datasets (upwards of 60k rows in a csv file) that I need to ingest in elasticsearch on a daily basis (to keep the data updated).

I currently have two lambda functions handling this.

Lambda 1:
A python lambda (nodejs would run out of memory doing this task) is triggered when a .csv file is added to S3 (this file could have upwards of 60k rows). The lambda converts this to JSON and saves to another S3 bucket.

Lambda 2:
A nodejs lambda that is triggered by .json files generated from the Lambda 1. This lambda uses the elasticsearch bulk api to try and insert all of the data into ES.

However because of the large amount of data we hit the ES api rate limiting and fail to insert much of the data.

I have tried splitting the data and uploading smaller amount at a time, however this would then be a very long running lambda function.

I have also looked at adding the data to a kinesis stream however even that has a limit to the data you can add to it in each operation.

I am wondering what the best solution may be to insert large amounts of data like this into ES. My next thought is possibly splitting the .json files into multiple .json files and trigger the lambda that adds data to ES for each smaller .json file. However I am concerned that I would still just hit the rate limiting of the ES domain.

Edit* Looking into the kinesis firehose option this seems like it is the best option as I can set the buffer size to maximum 5mb (this is the ES bulk api limit).

However firehose has an import limit of 1mb so I'd still need to do some form of processing on the lambda that pushes to firehose to split up the data before pushing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest designing the application to use SQS for queuing your messages rather than using firehose (which is more expensive and perhaps not the best option for your use case). Amazon SQS provides a lightweight queueing solution and is cheaper than Firehose (https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/)

Below is how it can work -

1. Lambda 1 converts each row to JSON and posts each JSON to SQS.
   (Assuming each JSON is less than 256KB)
2. the SQS queue acts as an event source for Lambda 2 and triggers it in batches of, say 5000 messages.
   (Ref - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html)
3. Lambda 2 uses the payload received from SQS to insert into ElasticSeach using the Bulk API.

Illustration -
[image]

The batch size can be adjusted based on your observation of how the lambda is performing. Make sure to adjust the visibility timeout and set up DLQ for efficient running.

This also reduces the S3 cost by avoiding storing the JSON in S3 for the 2nd Lambda to pick up. The data gets stored into ElasticSearch, hence duplication of data should be avoided.

Comment: This is genius, honestly not sure why I didn't think of this before. I don't think I really thought about processing the messages in a batch which makes total sense. Thanks. I'm going to give this a go.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially create one record per row and push it to firehose. When the data in the firehose stream reaches the buffer size configured it will be flushed to ES. This way only one lambda is required which can process rhe records from the csv and push to firehose